# Zoom and Pan JQuery compatibility with website Conflicts? Image not being displayed, script is being loaded

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been implementing the Zoom and Pan feature http://bit.ly/u9nlxS that works in isolation quite well as you can see. But when I import it into the website: http://bit.ly/uHrh3E the script gets called as you can see from using firebug, but there is no image being displayed. I've shortened the URLs as I don't want the website to be appear in a google search, which has happened in the past.

At first I thought it was a conflict with other scripts so I used var j = jQuery.noConflict(); but this didn't seem to work.

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/js/jquery.smoothZoom.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var j = jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function($){
    j('#eventsZoom').smoothZoom({
        width: 961,
        height: 546,
        pan_BUTTONS_SHOW: "NO",
        pan_LIMIT_BOUNDARY: "NO",
        button_SIZE: 24,
        button_ALIGN: "top right",  
        initial_POSITION: '1000 700',
        button_ALIGN: 'top left',
        initial_ZOOM: '80',
        zoom_MAX: 100,
        pan_BUTTONS_SHOW: 'YES',
        pan_LIMIT_BOUNDARY: 'YES',
        border_TRANSPARENCY: 20
    });
});

 </script>
```

I also omitted the other scripts again this didn't work. I'm slowly running out of ideas. As it can't be the image, the scripts is getting loaded. Could it be something to do with z-index perhaps?

How does one trouble shout these issues further? Can anyone other an insight into this issue please.

Comment: I see 3 errors when I load your website. It seems your scripts are added pretty badly.

Comment: You are loading jQuery 1.6.2 twice and jQuery 1.3.2 once. Please try to correct this first.

Comment: Fixed it you were both correct, combination of poorly imported .js and  the two images not being imported properly. Thank you for the heads up !